# Passing string literal to C

Tags: c, string, go, cgo

I'm playing around with calling C code in go. When I try to use `printf` from go however, I get a warning about the format string not being a string literal:

```
package main

// #include <stdio.h>
import "C"

func main() {
    C.printf(C.CString("Hello world\n"));
}
```

Warning:

> warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]

How can I pass a string literal into a C function like `printf`? Is there a function similar to `C.CString()` that I can use, or is it impossible and I should ignore this warning?

Comment: please try `C.printf("%s",C.CString("Hello world\n"));`

Comment: @AnkitB that doesn't work; if it did then I could have simply used `C.printf("Hello world\n");`

Comment: Why `printf` in particular?  Is there an overriding reason for it?  The warning as written is correct: the code as written is passing into C's `printf` a value that is technically constructed at runtime.  It's well known that dynamic values in the first position of `printf` can be a vector for attack.  C doesn't have any prejudices: all it knows is that there's some value in the first position for `printf` and it's not a literal string token.  The compiler is giving a legitimate compiler-time warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using printf, the format string is better to be a string literal and not a variable. And C.CString is coverted char pointer by go runtime. And also you may not use variadic arguments of printf in latest go. In other case, if you want to remove the warnings, Use type cast:

```
package main

/*
typedef const char* const_char_ptr;
#include <stdio.h>
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    C.puts((C.const_char_ptr)(C.CString("foo")))
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that call free for C.CString.

```
package main

/*
typedef const char* const_char_ptr;
#include <stdio.h>
*/
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    ptr := (C.const_char_ptr)(C.CString("foo"))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
    C.puts(ptr)
}
```